# Suggestions for structuring Hilt modules in a clean Android Architecture with multiple modules

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger-2, dagger-hilt, clean-architecture

So, there are ton of questions nudging this topic - but I have constraints, or preferences, restricting some of the solutions available. I am looking for innovative, neat, clean alternatives!
`Hilt version 2.44.2`

#### The Setup

`:app` module - Presentation layer; Activities, navigation, Compose/Views, ViewModels, lifecycle handling etc.

*Dependencies ->* `:domain` `:core`

---

`:domain` module - Domain models, Use Cases and Repository interfaces used in those use cases. Also domain models and allround handling for business logic.

*Dependencies ->* `:core`

---

`:data` module - Handling of network, databases and transfer models needed for those services. **AND** the implementations of the repositories (interfaces) defined in the `:domain` model.

*Dependencies ->* `:domain` `:core`

---

`:core` module - Shared logic and util stuff - whatever you would want to have available in all modules.

---

#### The Problem

Each module will have the necessary "Hilt Modules" needed to provide interfaces and external classes etc.

But there's a problem with the setup above. Since `:data` depends on `:domain` (and not the other way around) there is nothing connecting the "Hilt Modules" in `:data` with the rest of the dependency graph!

A simple solution would be to add `:data` to the `:app` module, simply exposing the modules to the Hilt building process. But here's a restriction - `I do not want :app to have access to :data classes!` and I also don't want to have the needed dependency between modules.

What would be the coolest, or whatever adjective you like the most, implementation or solution this problem?

### `TL;DR`

How do I introduce the "Hilt Modules" located in a module that the `:app` module does not directly, or indirectly, have a "kotlin module" dependency towards.

`:app` -> `:domain` <- `:data` | Introduce `:data` "hilt modules" into `:app` graph without `:app` having access to `:data` classes.

Answer (score 0):

**TLDR;**

Simply just use the Kotlin `internal` class modifier on your data classes and the repository implementations, that way you grantee that your app will never see or use `:data` classes.

===============

I can totally relate to your situation, in clean architecture it is a must to keep all the dependencies pointing to the `:domain` module and in your case `:domain` should never depend on any other modules, in fact it should remain with no dependencies on other modules to the point if you moved it to another project it should compile successfully.

> How do I introduce the "Hilt Modules" located in a module that the :app module does not directly, or indirectly, have a "kotlin module" dependency towards.

My suggested solution is simple, You actually mentioned it

> A simple solution would be to add `:data` to the `:app` module

And in order to tackle your concern

> without :app having access to :data classes.

Simply just use the Kotlin `internal` class modifier on your data classes and the repository implementations, that way you grantee that your app will never see or use `:data` classes.

This approach is adopted in the most projects i worked on and In [Google's Now In Android sample](https://github.com/android/nowinandroid/blob/main/app/build.gradle.kts)

PS : Don't forget to provide binding for your repository interfaces in Hilt [read more](https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/hilt-android#inject-interfaces).

[image: Now In Android's modules structure]

Comment: Sure, that would do it. And it's a simple solution, but it's not very sexy, is it. You need to manage all the files in `:data` continuously to make sure they have the internal modifier.
It's a much better solution than "implementing all hilt modules in the `:app` layer"